# Images used in my ios app

Tags: ios, image

Do I need to make a 2xpng for all images used in my ios app or just for my icon and launch images.  I have put all images in my supporting files folder.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a `@2x` image for any image that you don't want to appear pixelated when your app is used on a retina device. If an image looks the same either way then you don't need a `@2x` version of that image. Very few icons and no images work this way.

Basically you need both sizes of every image in your app otherwise they won't look right.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not necessary to create all image to 2xpng, 2xpng used when you are using retina display divice, but icon launch image and background will be in 2xpng format.

Comment: Thanks for the information. If I want my app to run on iphone 3s and iphone4 and iphone5, do I need all images to be 2xpng as well as regular png?.

Comment: it will be good but not necessary ,but yes icon and launch image is compulsory,not sure about background images.